# MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery even when Wrapped under the MaterialApp Widget

Tags: flutter

I can't access the MediaQuery.of() in the MaterialApp widget within the themeData method referencing the screenHeight & screenWidth variables.

I've tried to wrap the HomeScreen widget within a MaterialApp widget itself followed by a Scaffold widget, but this did not help.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 100;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100;

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(231, 13, 61, 1),
        textTheme: new TextTheme(
          title: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: screenHeight * 1.8,),
          body1: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: screenHeight * 1.8,),

        ),

      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppNavBar(),

      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget> [
            new Page1Widget(),
            Divider(height: 0, color: Colors.grey,),
            new Page2Widget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
        bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavBar(),

    );
  }
}
```

flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
flutter: MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
flutter: No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of().
flutter: This can happen because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce
flutter: a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.
flutter: The context used was:
flutter:   MyApp(dirty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only descendants of `MediaQuery` can access it. Which means you cannot build `MaterialApp.theme` based on theme.

If you need to, you can use `MaterialApp.builder`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Theme(
      child: child,
    );
  },
  home: ...
)
```